# Mono runtime and system version

Tags: windows, mono

I try to load up a Windows application with Mono Runtime, but when I do it gives me the message saying;

```
Please upgrade your system. Windows XP and older are not supported.
```

how can I change the system version later than XP with Mono? I know to change it for Wine but Mono Runtime doesn't use wine configurations.

Comment: edit your system time to before end-of-life-time of Windows XP (before April 8, 2014) and even disable the system time from up-timing through internet and if it's necessary **disconnect your Internet connection** until you are using that program.

Comment: This method doesn't work with Mono runtime. There has to be another way of configuring Mono to use a later build to run off.

Answer (score 0):

well Mono is cross platform, so is not depending about mono... i guess in ur windows applicationt there is a a check about System Verison
like if (System Versione is not equal to windwos 7 or 8 ) then trhow and exception and close application....